# "Tell to someone" or "tell someone"?

Tags: meaning, comparison

Sometimes, I have noticed that people, who are around me say sentences like:

> **You tell to John**.

instead of something like

> **You tell John**.

Please tell, is there any meaning difference in these two?

Comment: "Tell someone" is way more acceptable than "tell to someone", at least. I was taught that "tell to someone" is incorrect!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"You tell to John." is not a complete sentence. It has an indirect object, but no direct object. To be correct, you would need to add something, namely, the information you want them to "tell to John."

Tell [it/this/that/something] to John.

"You tell John." is an appropriate elision if previous context makes it obvious what it is that you want him/her to tell John.

Comment: Thank you Brain. In above explanation (what it is that you want him/her to tell to John) you have used "tell to John". could you please tell me? Why? Is it differen then other one

Comment: I could have just as well said "what it is that you want him/her you to tell John."  Good catch though. I don't mean you can't ever say "tell to John"; just that in itself, alone, it does not make a sentence.

Comment: @CharmiSapariya The object is still there, but it's been **relativized**: "the informationᵢ [ (that/which) you want them to tell ＿ᵢ to John ]"

Comment: Thank you Snailboat. Is it (relativized) applicable to all VERB or OBJECT or How is that?

Answer (score 0):

In most of the cases, the verb 'tell' is transitive. This simply means, it requires a direct object. Check out [OALD for the usage of this verb with good examples.](http://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/tell?q=tell)

However, it's worth noting that the verb **can also be used** as an intransitive verb. On the same page, it's mentioned.

So, to answer your question, most of the speakers (including me) would go for the latter sentence.

> You **tell  <del>to</del> John**

Comment: Incorrect. *tell* is transitive in *to tell a story* or *to tell a lie*, but in *You tell John* it is not, because *John* is not its direct object. Telling is not something that happens to John, cf. *kill John*.

Comment: Also compare: *thank John* (transitive) and *help John* (not transitive).